# Error message from worker: generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am having some issue with one of Dataflow jobs. From time to time I get this error messages. It seems that after this errors, the job keeps running fine, but, this night it actually stuck, or it started to slowly process the elements.
Also you can see from the screenshot that the workers started to behave very weirdly as shown in the CPU usage chart in the below screenshot.

```
Error message from worker: 
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
passed through: ==> dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631   generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
passed through: ==> dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631   generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
passed through: ==> dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631 generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
passed through: ==> dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631   generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
passed through: ==> dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631   generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.   
generic::aborted: SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That error message could be due to a wide variety of causes, so unless the error message is accompanied by the other behavior the user described, this could be due to any number of [errors](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors).

In my case, it was due to the **IO error: No space left on disk**

A good way to further investigate is by viewing the

- [**Diagnostics**](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#accessing_job_monitoring_charts) : table showing where errors occurred along the chosen timeline and possible recommendations for your pipeline.

[image]

Comment: How can I check this? Workers monitoring seems fine, logs show nothing related to disk space or something like this.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru Have you also checked your Job logs? What about your diagnostics section as I highlighted on the screenshot attached to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I've checked and is nothing in there, here are 2 screenshots 
https://ibb.co/sbQf4f6
https://ibb.co/j5Fftdj

Comment: Can you confirm whether your job's CPU was above or below 80%?

Comment: From my observations, these errors appear during autoscaling, and the CPU is below 80%

Comment: I see. This would need further investigation. I recommend for you to report it on https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. Once you do so, you can provide me with your issue tracker number.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru did you ever get an answer on this one? I see the same issue when dataflow is trying to autoscale even if the number of workers already are the same as max number of workers.

Comment: @robertsahlin no, It disappeared in the meantime without me doing something.

Answer (score 0):

It took me more than 1 day to figure out what SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected meant. In the dataflow job console, right hand top side it states what SDK it uses. In my case it said Apache Beam Python 3.9 SDK 2.44.0. However the base image I was using for my custom container was

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.44.0
```

as that what was provided in the many guides/tutorials I found, even by google. Only after aligning it with the version stated in the console, it was then when it started working.

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.9_sdk:2.44.0
```

Hopefully this helps some people

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-step Dataflow job that performs manipulation of the elements but also also requests data from Datastore.

I dissected the logs as stated in the [troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#error-syncing-pod) and saw a variety of errors, including "Error syncing pod ... failed to "StartContainer". Unfortunately, the job logs don't indicate why my code is causing the SDK container startup to fail. Examples of other logs I saw:

- generic::cancelled: Data channel closed, unable to receive additional data from SDK
- Marking the worker as unhealthy, since the required number of SDK Harnesses haven't registered with the Unified Worker.
  Expected 2 SDK Harnesses, but only 0 registered.
- Received crash notification for python3.8[1914] sig 11, user 0 group 0 (filtered out)
- Completing WorkerStatus() connection for SDK harness sdk-0-1 which is unexpected unless the job is being terminated.
- Skipping pod synchronization" err="PLEG is not healthy: pleg has yet to be successful

I tried a few changes to the pipeline. These changes included cleaning up the SDK container dependencies, upgrading machine types, trying SDK experiments as pipeline options. The Dataflow job still failed to establish the SDK containers on startup. Dataflow failed to distribute multiprocessing code I wrote from [this library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to different workers because this code was located outside of one of my DoFn classes. This block of code requests data from Datastore using multiple subprocess. It was excluded from the DoFn class because the Datastore client cannot be pickled.

I fixed the issue by removing the code that used the multiprocessing library. Instead, I use a simple loop to fetch entities from Datastore. Although not as performant as I would like, it works!