# Error message from worker: Data channel closed, unable to receive additional data from SDK sdk-0-0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We're running a Dataflow job on GCP using Apache Beam Python 3.9 SDK 2.45.0. For that, we're using a setup.py file that contains the packages to be installed on the worker machine. While installing the packages, we get the following error:

```
Python exited: signal: killed
```

Upon looking in the error logs, we found the following errors:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It looks like it is having trouble running the python script, Can you try choosing a machine type with higher memory with your notebook?

Comment: I tried with `n1-standard-4`. In that case, the `Python exited: status: killed` doesn't show up in the logs. But the other errors are still there.

Comment: Understood, Can you try with this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75448288/19378826 Match your base image custom container's sdk to what is displayed in your console as mentioned in the answer

Comment: I am using the Apache Beam Python 3.9 SDK 2.45.0. The same works in my local, but not on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline on how to troubleshoot errors in the Dataflow pipeline.

You will need to look into the worker logs for the root cause.

- Are you able to install the setup.py, that you pass to the Dataflow, on your local successfully?

Comment: The setup.py installation is working fine on the local.
In the GCP when I look at the Diagnostics tab, it shows the following error:
The worker VM had to shut down one or more processes due to lack of memory.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the `worker logs` to find the root cause.